# C# Compare two list of same object type

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to compare two list of same type using multiple properties of that type.

For example,

I have a class named Details

```
public class Details
{
    public   int id;
    public string symbol;
    public string code;
}
```

I have below two lists:

```
List<Details> list1 = new List<Details>();  
List<Details> list2 = new List<Details>();

list1.Add(new Details() { id=1,symbol="ANSI",code="NITE"});
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 1, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CALGO" });
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 1, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CANT" });
list1.Add(new Details() { id=2,symbol="ANSI",code="NITE"});
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 2, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CALGO" });
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 2, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CANT" });

list2.Add(new Details() { id = 1, symbol = "ANSI", code = "NITE" });
list2.Add(new Details() { id = 1, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CALGO" });
list2.Add(new Details() { id = 2, symbol = "ANSI", code = "NITE" });
```

I want only that data from List1 which has same id, symbol but different code.

So, in above scenario result will be as below.

```
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 1, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CANT" });
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 2, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CALGO" });
list1.Add(new Details() { id = 2, symbol = "ANSI", code = "CANT" });
```

It would be great if this can be achieved through Linq instead of using foreach.

I tried below but that's not correct.

```
var temp =list1.Where(x=>list2.Any(z=>x.id==z.id && string.Equals(x.symbol,z.symbol) && !string.Equals(x.code,z.code)));
```

Comment: Use a Join.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need rows to satisfy *two* conditions, not one, in order to make the output:

- There needs to be a match on `id` and `symbol`, and
- There must be no match on `id`, `symbol`, and `code`.

Here is how to do that with LINQ directly:

```
var tmp = list1.Where(x=>
    list2.Any(z=>x.id==z.id && x.symbol==z.symbol)
&& !list2.Any(z => x.id==z.id && x.symbol==z.symbol && x.code==z.code));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/kV0TWV)

An alternative based on applying [*De Morgan's laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
var tmp = list1.Where(x=>
    list2.Any(z=>x.id==z.id && x.symbol==z.symbol)
 && list2.All(z => x.id!=z.id || x.symbol!=z.symbol || x.code!=z.code));
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XyLPX7)

Answer (score 6):

**1)** I would first override `Equals` (and also `GetHashCode`)

```
public class Details
{
    public int id;
    public string symbol;
    public string code;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (id + symbol + code).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Details;
        if (other == null) return false;

        return id == other.id && symbol == other.symbol && code == other.code;
    }
}
```

Then you can use Linq as

```
var result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

It returns the result you expect...

---

**2)** Same result can also be obtained without changing the `Details` object and by implementing a custom `IEqualityComparer`

```
public class DetailsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Details>
{
    public bool Equals(Details x, Details y)
    {
        return x.id == y.id && x.symbol == y.symbol && x.code == y.code;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Details obj)
    {
        return (obj.id + obj.symbol + obj.code).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then your linq would be

```
var result = list1.Except(list2, new DetailsComparer()).ToList();
```

Those ways are better than O(n*n) algorithms utilizing of `Any` and `All`

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can do compare like your code, but if you want your code are more structure you can override method `Equals()` and Operator `==`:

```
public class Details
{
    public int id;
    public string symbol;
    public string code;

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Details detail = obj as Details;
        if ((System.Object) detail == null) {
          return false;
        }

        return (id == detail.id) && (symbol == detail.symbol);
    }

    public bool Equals(other) {
        return this.id == other.id && this.symbole == other.symbol;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return id ^ symbol.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then you can compare two Detail object directly.

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
public class DetailsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Details>
{

    public bool Equals(Details x, Details y)
        => x.id == y.id && x.symbol == y.symbol && x.code == y.code;

    public int GetHashCode(Details obj)
         => obj.code.GetHashCode();
}
```

And use wery simple this

```
var x = list1.Except(list2, new DetailsComparer());
```

result x:

1, ANSI, CANT

2, ANSI, CALGO

2, ANSI, CANT